# Show link URL on mouse position

Tags: url, mouse, mouseover, preview, mousehover

I'm looking for a browser addon, userscript or some simple way that would display the URL of a link on the mouse position instead of the bottom left corner, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lof5u.png) for example.

Edit:
It was easier than I thought, got it working with an one line userscript.

https://jsfiddle.net/0b819fx4/

```
var tooltipSpan = document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.title = a.href);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly whats your requirement but seems you are looking for some title. Can you try with this:

```
<a title="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lof5u.png" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lof5u.png">this</a>
```

This will show a popup when you hover over the anchor tab.